# Delete from <Map>

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary

I have mapping:

```
<class name="User" table="Users" lazy="false">
  <id name="id" type="Int32" column="id">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <property name="name" column="name" type="String"/>
  <map name="Urls" table="UserUrl" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all">
     <key column="user_id"></key>
     <index column="url_type_id" type="Int32"/>
     <one-to-many class="UserUrl"/>
   </map>
</class>

<class name="UserUrl" table="UserUrl" lazy="false">
  <id name="id" type="Int32" column="id">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property name="user_id" column="user_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/>
  <property name="UrlType" column="url_type_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/>
  <property name="Url" column="url" type="String" not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

Also I get

```
class User
{
  IDictionary<int,UserUrl> Urls;
 ....
}

User currentUser = FindById(2);
currentUser.Urls.Remove(5);
```

So I remove one item from assosiation collection of Url. Then I call `SaveOrUpdateCopy(...)`, But url from  table `UserUrl` doesn't delete and there is no error.

Does anybody know how to delete child item from collection and from DB?

Answer (score 1):

Set inverse to false for <map> element.

Comment: I try it, but I get error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'user_id', table 'dbo.UserUrl'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<map name="Urls" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphans">
```

- You don't need `table`, because the table is defined in the class `UserUrl` mapping
- You should not make it inverse, if it is not
- You should cascade it all-delete-orphan to tell NH to remove items that are removed from the collection.

---

Not related to your questions, why do you have this in the url?

```
<property name="user_id" column="user_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/>
```

You are mapping the foreign key there! I would never ever dare to do this.

---

Actually, I'm not sure if you should not actually map it like this:

```
<map name="Urls" table="UserUrl" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphans">
   <key column="user_id"/>
   <index column="url_type_id" type="Int32"/>
   <composite-element>
     <property name="UrlType" column="url_type_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/>
     <property name="Url" column="url" type="String" not-null="true"/>
   </composite-element>
 </map>
```

If the Url is not an independent entity, having an own Id, then you could map it as composite-element. The url is treated as a value type. There is no class `UserUrl` mapping anymore.

**Edit:**

- See the [NH Reference Chapter 7](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-7/1nr4enxv3dpeq/10), it explains the components.
- If you get not-null problems on references, just remove the not-null
  constraint on the foreign key. NH needs to insert some columns to get
  primary keys if you use `generator class="identity"`, so it stores
  a null temporary.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I use :<property name="user_id" column="user_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/> to insert new UserUrl. I try to delete it from mapping and class and get error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'user_id' table 'dbo.UserUrl'" so it is nessesary

Answer (score 0):

I try search in google but there is no information about difference between `<map><one-to-many >` and `<map><composite-element>` so I use `<map><one-to-many >`.
  `<map name="Urls" table="UserUrl" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphans">
   <key column="user_id"/>
   <index column="url_type_id" type="Int32"/>
   <composite-element>
     <property name="UrlType" column="url_type_id" type="Int32" not-null="true"/>
     <property name="Url" column="url" type="String" not-null="true"/>
   </composite-element>
 </map>`

---

If the Url is not an independent entity, having an own Id, then you could map it
as composite-element. The url is treated as a value type.
There is no class UserUrl mapping anymore.
I use UserUrl class in other code

Comment: You didn't understand components. See my answer, I added a Link. Btw, don't answer to your question if you are actually commenting to an answer. You could be down-voted.

Comment: Forgot to tell you this secret: you can select several lines together and make the appearing as source code (this just adds 4 spaces before each line). It also breaks on each line and has some pretty syntax highlighting. Don't use <pre>, <br>, <hl> aso. Just select text and use the buttons on top of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

> -Btw, don't answer to your question if you are actually commenting to an
>   answer. You could be  down-voted

-The problem is that I have no stackoverflow account, so only one way to login to site on the same name is to enter name and email under my post. I try to register account on that site with the same name and email, but when I log in it treats me as new user (not as I login fist time).
So I have no choice.

Also I find out that working code is

```
<map name="Urls" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphans" inverse="true">
```

without inverse="true" it doesn't work.